# Where should i set my db object in my model ? (MVC)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

I would like to know where is the best place to set my db object with my model.

Should I hard coded it since my model should be designed for one project, so i set it inside my constructor or wherever i do initialization ?
or
Should I pass my db object to my constructor when instancing my object ?

What is the best way, i mean from experimented users, and efficient that'll give me more confort to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Most PHP projects that utilize a database connection represent that database using a [Singleton pattern][1], if you aren't sure what this is, read up on it.
2. Typically I define my database connections in a configuration file which can easily be changed between environments (development, stage, production).
3. I'll then instantiate my database connection in a bootstrap file using the aforementioned Singleton pattern and configuration file.
4. My models will typically completely abstract the database/table data store, for each model I'll do something like this:

bootstrap.php
<?php

```
$config = load_config_data(ENVIRONMENT);

Db::setDefaultAdapter($config['database']);
```

Model/Table/User.php
<?php

```
class Table_User extends Db_Table 
{
  // Table name
  protected $_name = 'user';

  /* Do a bunch of database specific stuff */
}
```

Model/User.php

update(
          array('username'=>$username),
          Db::quoteInto('userid = ?', $userid)
        );
      }
    }

This is pretty much an introduction to the [Model][2] in the [Zend Framework MVC][3], I would check it out for some ideas on how to organize your code (or save yourself some trouble and actually use the [framework][4].)


  [1]: https://www.php.net/singleton
  [2]: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html
  [3]: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.html
  [4]: http://framework.zend.com

Answer (score 1):

For testability, you should pass it into the constructor rather than hard coding it. This helps you to write unit test because you can mock your DB object.

Answer (score 0):

I would not hard code it, even if the code is never used for another project simply moving from a test database to a live database may require locating and changing the code in the model class. That would be far better placed in some kind of configuration file.

Personally, I would have the db object defined in whatever you use as a bootstrap - and then have the model(s) use that single object.